# Picking the most common element from a number of factors

Tags: r

Lets say I have 3 factors, each has 2 levels: 'a' and 'b':

```
> b <- factor(c('b', 'b', 'a'))
> a <- factor(c('a', 'b', 'a'))
> c <- factor(c('a', 'a', 'a'))
```

I want to create fourth factor that on every position contains the most common element from this 3 factors, so, in this example, it would look like this:

```
> d
[1] a b a
Levels: a b
```

Is there a way of performing this kind of operation with some "smooth" function, or do I have to use "if" conditions?

Comment: Can you guarantee each factor has the same levels? You say it, but your `c` variable only has `'a'` and you don't specify `levels = c("a", "b")`.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I did not notice. Each factor has the same levels.

Comment: Also, do you need a solution that generalizes to more than 2 levels? And would it be okay to reorder the levels?

Comment: what if there are no max freq? `d<-factor(c('a','b','c'))`

Comment: @Gregor solution for any number of levels in general, and yes, you could reorder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try

```
factor(apply(data.frame(b, a, c), 1, Mode), levels = levels(a))
#[1] a b a
#Levels: a b
```

where `Mode` is

```
Mode <- function(x) {
 ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. You should not name something `c` though because that represents the concatenate function.

```
 bb <- factor(c('b', 'b', 'a'))
 aa <- factor(c('a', 'b', 'a'))
cc <- factor(c('a', 'a', 'a'))

dat <- data.frame(aa, bb, cc)

dd <- factor(apply(dat, 1, function(x) names(sort(table(x), decreasing = TRUE))[1]))

dd

[1] a b a
Levels: a b

> dat
  aa bb cc
1  a  b  a
2  b  b  a
3  a  a  a
```

Comment: I know, it was just for example purposes - still my mistake, thanks for pointing that out.